# After El Capitan upgrade, pdfcrop does not crop pdf files

Tags: pdfcrop

I have recently upgraded to El Capitan, and pdfcrop produces an output file, but does not crop the file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome! Any details? Have you installed MacTeX 2015? Have you updated it? Have you configured your editor (if applicable) or updated it (if applicable and available)? Errors? Log? From command line? Does compilation work for 'Hello world!'? Have you followed the instructions provided by TUG? In answers on this site?

Comment: I updated my version of texshop (check for errors) and I can get tex files to compile just fine, but running the command-line pdfcrop ruby script just doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't get the pdfcrop perl script to crop the pdfs (http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/), a work around is the bash script linked below seems to work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270493/how-to-crop-a-multi-page-image-scanned-pdf-file-which-wont-crop-with-pdfcrop